# Allowing Windows to communicate with USB devices when locked

Tags: windows-10, usb, serial-port

Using Windows 10, is there an option to let Windows communicate with a USB device when the user account screen is locked?

#### Example:

1. User connects a USB device that has an LED connected to it.
2. User runs a program in the background which makes the LED blink (by sending info through USB).
3. User presses <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to lock the screen.

---

**What happens:** the "LED USB device" won't get the info from the program and stops blinking.

**What I'd like to happen:** The LED will continue blinking as the program keeps running in background.

Comment: There's no reason the application controlling the LED can't continue executing it's code when Windows is locked. Observe that many other applications do this just fine. If this isn't working, it's the application's fault.

Comment: @Noam I also have this issue.  Did you solve this issue?  If so, please provide the solution as an answer below.

Comment: @Steven My problem was with my Corsair equipment, and apparently it's by design; When I wrote an application to run a led strip animation, it kept working when the computer was locked.